# When link to the page dynamic only shows information on the first table in all links

Tags: php

In the site that I am creating presents in a page all the news with 1 dynamic link that this creates a page with the content of this news however all generated links will always stop to the first value of the database and not to the ID that is intended. Someone can help me? Thank you.

Page to generate links

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbyXK.jpg

Page of any displayed link shows only the first value of the table.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjclF.jpg

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){

    $ID = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_GET['id']);

    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "base_de_dados_museu");

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM destaques where id='$ID'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die ("bad query: $sql");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die ("bad query: $sql");

    if(isset($_GET['post'])){
        $titulo = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_GET['titulo']);
        $image = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_GET['image']);
        $texto = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_GET['texto']);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO destaques (id, titulo, texto, image) VALUES ('$titulo', '$image', '$texto')";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die ("bad query: $sql");
    }
}
```

Comment: you use `$db`, before you define it.

Comment: i put the $db in first the samething happen.

Comment: you can see by the image... https://imgur.com/NdEOVtu

Comment: you still get "undefined variable .."?

Comment: yes i still get..

Comment: It is solved. Thanks for the help i did put now before like you say after i delete the cookies of the broswer and now it works. Thanks for the help! @tim

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in the code. I will list some of them but maybe there are others...

Four columns here but only three values:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO destaques (id, titulo, texto, image) VALUES ('$titulo', '$image', '$texto')";
```

The result variable is overwritten:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM destaques where id='$ID'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die ("bad query: $sql");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die ("bad query: $sql");
```